# Deleting row of FormArray in FormGroup is not correct for input fields in MatTable

Tags: angular, angular-material, formarray

I have MatTable, formed from formarray. When i deleting row, the values in input fields of my table are not changed as they should be. But in object all data after deleting row is as it should be. Helping only refresh table after deleting row, but i think it should work as is, without refreshing. I've make a example of this phenomenon: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vxupo?file=src/app/app.component.html)
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Its working fine. if 1 delete 1 or 2 and refresh it stay deleted.

Comment: Yes, it's working fine only with manual refresh (by pressing button 'Refresh'). But i sure it should be wokring automatically.

Comment: its even working automatically. If I delete any row it gets deleted.

Comment: I think you not understand the problem. Yes, it deleting but after as it deleted, fields Name is not accordance to their values in fields Count. For example: before delete: apple 1, banana 2, lemon3. AFTER delete of 1st row: banana 1, lemon 2. But should be banana 2, lemon 3, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove this property `[trackBy]="trackByIndex"` from your `<table>` tag, your problem will be resolved,

After reading your comment, try to modify your `trackByIndex` method like below,

```
trackByIndex(i, row: any) {
    return `${row.product_count}`;
}
```

Based on new comment with condition of cursor loose, you can try this approach, just modify your `deleteRow` method like below

```
deleteRow(row: any, index: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['tableFields'];
    control.removeAt(index);
    this.refreshTable(); // add this method, it will refresh your grid
}
```

Comment: Then the table loosing its tracking function, and start rerendering on every input, loosing the cursor in input field. In my work project (not in Stackblitz example) without [trackBy]="trackByIndex" i even can't put cursor into input field

Comment: I have modified my answer again, Please have a look

Comment: cursor still disappear after every symbol input ((

Comment: Can you do one more thing with you code, try to call this `refreshTable()` method within your `deleteRow()` method

Comment: "Can you do one more thing with you code, try to call this refreshTable() method within your deleteRow() method" - I'm just doing it like you said in my working project. But i think it is not right way? This solution is crutches (as talking in Russia:))

Comment: "I haven't understand it, what do you mean by cursor disappear? can you share pictorial example" - i renew my StackBlitz code with your suggestion. You can see what i means, if you put cursor in any input fields, and try to input any number with more than 1 digits. After the first digit inputed, cursor will disappear

Comment: "Can you do one more thing with you code, try to call this refreshTable() method within your deleteRow() method" - and plus to my comment above, when table is refreshing, all table is blinking - it is not good to user i think

Comment: I got it! for now try to put `refreshTable()` method within `deleteRow()` method, your problem will be resolved, but as you already mentioned, that you are not in favor of this approach - "I'm just doing it like you said in my working project. But i think it is not right way? This solution is crutches (as talking in Russia:))"

Comment: I've found a better decision i guess. No need to refresh all table (it blinking and it loss the scroll position if the table is long). Оnly need to update columns with inputs by delete them from array of columns  (or replacement by empty columns), and put them back. Then table is not blinking and staying at it's place if it long and scrollable. Here is the example with a replacement:

Comment: `refreshTableColumns(){
    this.displayedColumns.splice(2,1,'empty_f');
    this.displayedColumns.splice(4,1,'empty_p');
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.displayedColumns.splice(2, 1, 'actual_balance');
      this.displayedColumns.splice(4, 1, 'product_price');
    }, 1);
  }`